# Selenium identify and click Show description button

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-analysis

Using selenium I am trying to export the full job description of a job listing on Google jobs but I can't find the element that expands the job description.

[The show description button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f7tv.png)`

[Link to the web page](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+analyst+jobs+near+London&rlz=1C1ONGR_en-GBGB977GB977&oq=data+ana&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7Mg4IARBFGCcYOxiABBiKBTIGCAIQRRg7MgYIAxBFGDkyEAgEEAAYgwEYsQMYyQMYgAQyBggFEEUYPDIGCAYQRRg8MgYIBxBFGDzSAQgyMTA5ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ7uHdlJ6EAxVtTkEAHfinCDMQutcGKAF6BAgOEAU&sxsrf=ACQVn0-gdfTwZb6JyKrdpeH70jKbQwgrig:1707478403814#fpstate=tldetail&htivrt=jobs&htichips=date_posted:today&htischips=date_posted;today&htidocid=gR8sURIPiiVZDY-HAAAAAA%3D%3D)

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=data+analyst+jobs+near+London&rlz=1C1ONGR_en-GBGB977GB977&oq=data+&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggBEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg5MgYIARBFGDsyBggCEEUYOzIGCAMQRRg7MgYIBBBFGDwyBggFEEUYPDIGCAYQRRg8MgYIBxBFGDzSAQg2MTU4ajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj63MCW6qGEAxX3VfEDHbJDATkQutcGKAF6BAgeEAU#htivrt=jobs&fpstate=tldetail&htichips=date_posted:today&htischips=date_posted;today&htidocid=gR8sURIPiiVZDY-HAAAAAA%3D%3D'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Rejecting cookies
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
reject_button = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button")
reject_button.click()

# Applying filter for listings in past 24 hours
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get(url)

# Showing the full job description (where the problem arises)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
show_desc_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mCs3Sb') 
#not interactable
show_desc_button.click()
```

I have tried using using all of the elements that look to be related to the button but the closest I have come is 2 elements that return the following ElementNotInteractableException (the show_desc_button in my code is one example, the other has the following class name 'jJP9Pc'

I am aware that using an API would be a much better method but I want to try this method (assuming it is even feasible?).

Comment: I don't see any 'show full description' button? When I click on a job I see the 'Job Preview' but that's it.

Comment: @Obaskly When you scroll down in the job preview does the button appear like in the picture above?

Comment: No. Here's what it looks like to me: https://i.imgur.com/4GtYrpV_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand